# onClick didn't work inside form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Usually I see people use form to create input :

```
<form action="">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="Fname">First Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Fname" class="form-control" id="fname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="Lname">Last Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Lname" class="form-control" id="lname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="address">address</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" id="address"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="phone">phone</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit();"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

It's make my submit button didn't work, but as soon as I remove the form tag it's work :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="Fname">First Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Fname" class="form-control" id="fname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="Lname">Last Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Lname" class="form-control" id="lname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="address">address</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" id="address"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="phone">phone</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit();"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My js only like this :

```
var Fname= document.getElementById("fname");
var Lname= document.getElementById("lname");
var Address= document.getElementById("address");
var Phone= document.getElementById("phone");
var Result= document.getElementById("result");


function submit(){
    var valueFname=Fname.value;
    var valueLname=Lname.value;
    var valueAddress=Address.value;
    var valuePhone=Phone.value;
    Result.innerHTML="hello, "+valueFname+" "+valueLname+" good to see you. Your contact number is "+valuePhone+" , and your address "+valueAddress;
}
```

Why cant I wrap all my input inside form? does it need additional code?

Comment: form will for post data into database using get or post method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> its make my submit button didnt work

No, your submit button is working fine.  Therein lies the problem you're seeing, in fact.  Your JavaScript code is executing, but the time between showing any output and reloading the page because you've submitted a form is nearly instantaneous.

So your JavaScript works.  And your form works.  Everything works.

> but as soon as i remove the form tag its work

Not quite.  When you remove the `form` tag the form submission *no longer works*.  All you've done is prevent the form from submitting, because you no longer have a form.

> why cant i wrap all my input inside form?

You can.  But it really depends on what you're trying to do.  If you have a form and you want to submit it, use a `form` element.  If you don't want to submit anything as a form, you can leave it out.  That's its only purpose.

You can have inputs on the page anywhere you like, they don't need to be in forms.  If you just want to interact with them via JavaScript then you can do that without a `form` element.

Comment: ***Your JavaScript code is executing, but the time between showing any output and reloading the page because you've submitted a form is nearly instantaneous.***. so how to show the output sir. cause as you say it nearly instantaneous

Comment: @vandi: Doesn't your second example successfully do that?  If you don't need the `form` at all, simply omit it.  You *can* prevent the form from submitting (see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission), but if you never want to submit the form then it seems reasonable to not have it in the first place.

Comment: @vandi You could still use a form, but just prevent it form submitting by calling the method on form submit and returning false. https://jsfiddle.net/kpduncan/0nbjcnw7/

Answer (score 0):

Forms are made to make HTTP methods (such as POST or PUT).
So, if you need that input's information take part in a http method, you NEED TO use form.
If your Submit button is made just for internal stuff, don't use form.

A little more information: [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Form will send the data to the file specified in action and this event is triggered by `<input type="submit"/>` inside a form.

You can use a `<button>` tag inside form to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the action for your form, it is empty.

Or you can use [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Had to poke you on a old post, you approved this http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/123007 as documentation, please read a bit before approving documentation! This clearly a question, and not in any kind documentation... Flag this comment as too chatty to get it removed afterwards!

Comment: Hah! Yup, probably! ;)